# Code Optimisation on trigger (Task) updating parent record (Case)

Tags: trigger

I wrote a trigger on **Task** to update related **Case** field **Task_CreatedDate__c** with Task **CreatedDate** when task is linked to a **Case** or to *NULL* when task is no longer linked to the Case
or Task is deleted

The trigger works fine, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to write it.
Thanks

```java
trigger TaskCreatedDateToCase on Task (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    
    Map<Id, DateTime> taskCreatedDateMap = new Map<Id, DateTime>();
  
    //Update Case field "Task_CreatedDate__c" when Task is created
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
            taskCreatedDateMap.put(t.WhatId, t.CreatedDate);  
        }
        List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Task_CreatedDate__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN :taskCreatedDateMap.keySet()];
        for(Case c : caseList) {
            c.Task_CreatedDate__c = taskCreatedDateMap.get(c.Id);
        }
        update caseList;
    }
    
    //Update Case field "Task_CreatedDate__c" when Task WhatId field is updated
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
            taskCreatedDateMap.put(t.WhatId, t.CreatedDate);  
        }
        List<Case> caseList2 = [SELECT Task_CreatedDate__c FROM Case];
        List<Case> caseToUpdate = new List<Case>();
        for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
            for(Case c : caseList2) {
                if(t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId != Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).WhatId && taskCreatedDateMap.containsKey(c.Id)) {
                    c.Task_CreatedDate__c = taskCreatedDateMap.get(c.Id);
                    caseToUpdate.add(c);
                } else if(Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).WhatId == c.Id) {
                    c.Task_CreatedDate__c = null;
                    caseToUpdate.add(c);
                }
                
            }
        }
        System.debug('caseToUpdate ' +caseToUpdate);
        if(!caseToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update caseToUpdate;
        } 
    }
    
    //Update Case field "Task_CreatedDate__c" to null when Task is deleted
    if(Trigger.isDelete) {
        Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Task t : Trigger.old) {
            caseIds.add(t.WhatId);
        }
        List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Task_CreatedDate__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];
        for(Case c : caseList) {
            c.Task_CreatedDate__c = null;
        }
        update caseList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ideally be using a trigger framework and keeping the logic outside of the trigger. Beyond that though, what exactly are you looking to "optimize" here? If you don't have an answer to that, then it's not yet time to optimize (define a metric, measure it, _then_ optimize). Just making sure that there are no queries or DML inside of loops is usually enough. Also, can a Case have more than one Task? If so, then your existing logic doesn't handle that scenario.

Comment: @DerekF , Duly Noted. I will keep the logic outside the trigger. Apart from separating the trigger logic from the trigger itself, When I said optimize the code, I was looking at Trigger.isUpdate in particular as I have an inner loop. From what I understand, It is always better to avoid inner loop

Comment: For the second loop do you really need to run for all of `caseList2` couldn't you only iterate over the task that are related to that case?

Otherwise for performance analysis I recommend: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=financialforce.lana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the question is about nested loops.

Nested loops are not inherently evil. When you have nested data, nested loops are practically required.

The type of nested loop that we want to avoid are ones of the form

```java
for(object 1){
    for(object 2){
        if(object 1.field == object 2.field){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

If there are `N` object 1 instances, and `M` object 2 instances, then the inner loop will be executed `N * M` times, which very quickly gets out of hand.

Your nested loop looks similar enough to the "bad pattern" to be a concern. As a general rule of thumb, you want to track which child records belong to which parent records. If you only iterate over the child record(s) associated to the current parent record, then the inner loop only runs `N + M` times. When `N` and `M` are both 200, the "bad" approach will run the inner loop 40,000 times while the good approach will run 400 times.

I have some doubts that your code behaves correctly according to the description you've shared (Case's Task_Created_Date__c becomes null if the task is updated and remains on the same case?), but without a more complete description I could only guess at what needs to be done.

What I can say is that queries without a `WHERE` clause are a big red flag. Since your code only seems to care about the Case records related to one of the Task records you're processing, the `caseList2` query is not accomplishing anything for you and should be removed. Everything you're doing here can be handled by using `t.whatId` and the SObject constructor. Without that extra query, your inner loop disappears.

```java
if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
    // I like using maps instead of lists when there's a possibility that an Id
    //   can come up more than once (to avoid a "duplicate item in list" error when
    //   you go to DML update it)
    Map<Id, Case> casesToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, Case>();

    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        // Since WhatId is a polymorphic relationship field, it'd be a good idea
        //   to check that we're related to a Case first.
        // If we aren't, then we can skip this Task and move on to processing the next
        //   one.
        // The Id class can tell us what object we're working with
        // The Safe Navigation Operator (a.k.a. "SNO", `?.`) also takes care of the null WhatId scenario
        // If WhatId is null, the SNO will return null and not call getSObjectType()
        // Since null != a case, we'll get into this if() block
        if(t.WhatId?.getSObjectType() != Case.SObjectType){ continue; }

        // If you have the Id of an SObject you want to update (or delete), then you
        //   don't need to query.
        // Just use the SObject constructor to set the Id for a new instance
        Case c = new Case(
            Id = t.WhatId,
            // I also like to assume a default value and try to show that it should
            //   be some other value.
            // Just a way to reduce typing a bit (and keep things as un-indented as possible)
            Task_CreatedDate__c = null
        );

        if(t.WhatId != Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).WhatId){
            c.Task_Created_Date__c = t.CreatedDate;
        }

        casesToUpdateMap.put(c.Id, c);
    }

    // Because the SNO in the loop prevents us from working on Tasks not related to another
    //   object, this line isn't necessary (because that if() means it's impossible
    //   for the Case Id to be null).
    // But... if it were possible, we can easily remove the null Id from the map outside
    //   of the loop
    //casesToUpdateMap.removeKey(null);

    // DML requires a list or a single instance, so we've gotta call .values()
    //   to get a list from our map.
    // No need to check if it's empty or not.
    // Salesforce won't execute the DML (nor count it against you) if the list is empty
    update casesToUpdateMap.values();
}
```

Without trying to assume too much, I believe that one thing your trigger fails to consider is *what happens to the previous Case that a Task was related to?* Surely it should not continue to have the created date of the Task it no longer has. Going with the theme of your existing code, I'd think the old Task should be updated to null.

```java
// Comments from the previous iteration of this code have been removed
// Go through the previous iteration if you need more explanation of what things
//   do or what their purpose is
if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
    Map<Id, Case> casesToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, Case>();

    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.WhatId?.getSObjectType() != Case.SObjectType){ continue; }

        Case c = new Case(
            Id = t.WhatId,
            Task_CreatedDate__c = null
        );

        // When you re-use something more than once in a loop, it almost always
        //   pays to put it into a variable
        Id oldWhatId = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id).WhatId;

        if(t.WhatId != oldWhatId){
            c.Task_Created_Date__c = t.CreatedDate;

            // Take care of the old Case as well
            // Just assume that the old WhatId isn't null for now
            casesToUpdateMap.put(oldWhatId, new Case(
                Id = oldWhatId?.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType ? oldWhatId : null,
                Task_CreatedDate__c = null
            ));
        }

        casesToUpdateMap.put(c.Id, c);
    }

    // In this case, the old value of t.WhatId _can_ be null, so running this
    //   line is a good idea (to guard against that possibility)
    casesToUpdateMap.removeKey(null);

    update casesToUpdateMap.values();
}
```

Now, if a Case can have multiple Tasks and you want to have the Case reflect the date of its most recently created Task, then you can't avoid having an additional query and a nested loop. The key to working through that scenario would be to:

- gather the WhatIds (both new and old)
- query for all Tasks where the WhatId matches any of the Ids you gathered
- iterate over the Tasks and build a `Map<Id, List<Task>>` (the key is the WhatId) to group Tasks by their parent record
- iterate over the map keys
- nested iteration to go through the list of Tasks for each parent Id

The "group the records by the parent value" bit is what gets you into `N + M` territory.

It's generally easier to do this with a parent-child subquery like

```
Map<Id, Account> accountWithOppsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]);
```

which has SOQL doing the "group children under each parent" bit for you